# how can I define an application static variable in php (you can call it a global shared cache in memory)?

Tags: php, asp.net

I am coming from asp.net world and I need to rewrite a small library from .net to php. My library needs to download a file from somewhere and use that information for all page requests (I do not want to have dependency on files or database). In asp.net  you can use static variables and those variables are shared between all page requests but as far as I know in php statics are behaving differently and are not shared between user requests.
What is the way to implement this library t in php?

Comment: There is really no such creature in PHP: you have to use some form of persisten storage, whether that's database, filesystem, cache (redis, memcached, etc). Though your best option may be shared memory (shmop).

Comment: @MarkBaker in this case I think users of my library will have to install and configure Shomp I have read "To use shmop you will need to compile PHP with the --enable-shmop parameter in your configure line." is it something convenient or might some people do not like to have Shomp installed in their web servers?(sorry if my question looks stupid I do not have any clue how configuring this libraries might be disturbing (from performance point view ) or hard

Comment: Most won't want to install it; and many hosting providers won't allow it. It might be worthwhile looking at [the PSR-16](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-16/) and writing a couple of generic caches to redis/database/filesystem that comply with that standard, and allowing others to write their own as well